# Div hides behind a div with "position:fixed"?

Tags: html, css, position, positioning

So I'm currently building a website for school and I've put the navigation bar so its fixed, but now the div slides behind the navigation bar, its really not that noticable but it is just bugging me. Does anyone know if there is a way to fix this?

Without the fixed positioning : http://prntscr.com/18kufb

With fixed positioning: http://prntscr.com/18kurb

The Website : http://penguin.baileywhite.vacau.com

CSS File http://penguin.baileywhite.vacau.com/library/css/style.css

I know its a lot to look at for so little to fix, its just really bugging me and if anyone can help fix this it would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Bailey.

Comment: What is the z-index? Is it css?

Comment: z-index is css, but that will move the div to display on top of the nav bar, and that is probably not what you want. Try to position the content dive using the css "Position: relative; top: Xpx;". Replace the Xpx with the height of your nav bar. That should do the trick.

Comment: yea didnt see the pics, just thought he meant something was covering his menu.

Comment: MDN explains the stacking concept quite well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_without_z-index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the `.pure-g-r` set `margin-top: 36px;` and on your `#nav` set `top: 0;`. This will assure you that your navigation will always stick to the top of the window.